# Modifying SYSDATE function

Tags: sql

In one of my SQL queries, I am using

`[... and z.READ_TIMESTAMP > TIMESTAMP_TO_EPOCH(TRUNC(SYSDATE-3)]`

If I want the date to be exactly 5/31/2017, will I use 'SYSDATE' (date-n) function or some other expression? or how can a modify my query for 5/31/2017

Comment: What database platform?  Looks like oracle.  trunc function will remove the time component.  So, What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date to be exactly 5/31/2017 then use **[TO_DATE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)** or **[TO_TIMESTAMP()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions229.htm#SQLRF06142)** depending on which data type you need (date or timestamp). As you are using SYSDATE already the the date data type should work.

```
-- e.g.
select
      to_date('5/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
    , to_timestamp('5/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
from dual

...
and z.READ_TIMESTAMP > TIMESTAMP_TO_EPOCH(to_date('5/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'))
```

**HOWEVER**

I suspect you may want more than just a way to establish a fixed date. For example are you asking for "how do I get that last day of the previous month?" which perhaps can be satisfied by using >= and the first day of current month like this:

```
...
and z.READ_TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP_TO_EPOCH(trunc(sysdate,'MM'))
```

or if it really is the last day of the previous month can be achieved with a combination of **[LAST_DAY()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm)** and **[ADD_MONTHS()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm)**

```
and z.READ_TIMESTAMP > 
TIMESTAMP_TO_EPOCH( last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-1)) )
```

Without knowing a great deal more about the nature of your data and query purpose please do note that each date you use when "truncated" also has the time  set to 00:00:000 - so IF you data contains time within a day other than 00:00:00 then these 2 queries might NOT produce the same  result

```
.... datetimecolumn > to_date('05/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') -- "a"

.... datetimecolumn >= to_date('06/01/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')  -- "b"
```

For example "a" the entire 24 hour duration of 05/31/2017 would be included in the results, but for example "b" that same 24 hour duration would be excluded from results. In my experience the last day of any month isn't really the best method for locating date/time based data, instead usually it is the first day of the next month that produces the correct result.